# Bash - How to properly list files in a folder and manage exclusion

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for a proper way to list

- all filenames (without extension)
- matching a specific extension list
- recursively in a specific folder
- with some exclusions patterns

and then export that to a file.

Currently i'm doing the following which is working properly:

```
ls -R --ignore={"Sample","Sample.*","sample.*","*_sample.*","*.sample.*","*-sample.*","*.sample-*","*-sample-*","*trailer]*"} "$filesSource" | grep -E '\.mkv$|\.mp4$|\.avi$' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' | sort >> "$listFile"
```

Thanks to [ShellChecker](https://www.shellcheck.net/), I have a feedback on this line and I don't know how to do that properly!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is basically telling you not to parse `ls` output. This is a good read about it: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try find command?

something like

find YOUR_PATH -type f -name "*.FIRST_EXTENSION" -o -name "*.SECOND_EXTENSION"| grep -v SOME_EXCLUSION | awk -F. '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort > SOME_FILE

note: this will work only if the filenames contain only 1 "." character for the extension, otherwise you need to modify a little bit the awk part.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching just on filenames, then you can use:

I split the command line in multiple lines:

```
$ find /path/to/folder -type f  \( \( -name '*.ext1' -or -name '*.ext2' -or -name '*.ext3' \) -and -not \( -name '*excl1*' -or -name 'excl2*' \) \) -print
```

This will do:

- `/path/to/folder`:  the folder you are searching
- `-type f` : you are searching for files in the above folder which satisfy
- `\(`: open the conditional test
- `\( -name '*.ext1' -or -name '*.ext2' -or -name '*.ext3' \)`: who have one of the three listed extensions (with a conditional or)
- `-and -not \( -name '*excl1*' -or -name 'excl2*' \)`: if the above condition mathches it will check (`-and`) if one of the patterns `*excl1*` or `excl2*` do `-not` match.
- `\)` close the main conditional test
- `-print` perform the action to print the found paths.